# Problems printing a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this function at the end of an .asp page (yes, the older asp).

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.print();
  printPage();

  function printPage() {
    if (confirm("The page was printed correctly?")){
      window.location.replace('Other.asp');
    } else{
      window.print();
      printPage();
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem apper when I execute the page and never appear the print options window. The shows the confirm window every time that I press the NO button but never shows the print windows.

Sorry for my english if I do a mistake ...

Thanks a lot !!!!
Gustavo from Argentina.-

Comment: Your printPage() function is calling your printPage() function.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're saying you never see the print dialogue - initially or whenever the confirmation returns "no"? And you're expecting the print dialogue to show initially, and whenever the confirmation returns "no"?

Comment: @DA.: I think that was intentional, but we'll see when they clarify...

Comment: That's got nothing to do with classic ASP, removing the tag.

Answer (score 1):

`window.print()` is executing asynchronously, so it's immediately calls your `printPage()` function. And so on and so on, if you press 'NO'.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421057/447356) correctly mentions, it's executing as soon as it's called, triggering the native print dialog and not waiting until the user actually prints (or cancels) the page. There is no way for you to know when this happens.

That said, one way around this is to put a message in the HTML document itself that will be initially hidden and become visible only after sending the print command:

```
<div id="pnlPrintConfirm" style="display: none;">
    The page was printed correctly? 
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.replace('Other.asp');">Yes</button> 
    <button type="button" onclick="printPage();">No</button>
 </div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function printPage() {
    //get placeholder element:
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("pnlPrintConfirm");

    //hide so it won't get printed after first print:
    oDiv.style.display = "none";

    //send print command:
    window.print();

    //show confirmation panel:
    oDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

Remember to call `printPage()` initially instead of the code you currently have.